# Axios version of a curl request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

I have following api request the I need to implement using axios
(taken from Expensify docs if you are wondering)

```
curl -X POST 'https://example/api' \
    -d 'requestJobDescription={
        "type":"file",
        "inputSettings":{
            "type":"combinedReportData",
            "filters":{
                "reportIDList":"1234567,2233445"
            }
        }
    }'
    --data-urlencode 'template@expensify_template.ftl'
```

Main issue is the --data-urlencode file being passed as a param

**Solution**
This is what worked for me (I was using encodeURI before this in the template param)

```
axios.post('https://example/api', null, { params: {
    requestJobDescription: `{
        "type":"file",
        "inputSettings":{
            "type":"combinedReportData",
            "filters":{
                "reportIDList":"1234567,2233445"
            }
        }
    }`,
    template: `<#-- Header -->
    Report ID,Amount,Category
    <#list reports as report>
        <#list report.transactionList as expense>
            \${report.reportID},<#t>
            \${(expense.amount/100)?string("0.00")},<#t>
            \${expense.category}<#lt>
        </#list>
    </#list>`
}})
```

Though I would still like to have template in an external file. Importing it causes unexpected token exception

Comment: You can use `encodeURI` as a replacement for `urlencode`

Comment: Also, check cURL to Fetch tool: https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/

Comment: Surprisingly removing encodeURI is what did the trick